# downloading pdf using requests not working

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

I written a code to download a pdf file from a link using request

```
import requests

url = "https://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/apbursaweb/download?id=231746&name=EA_DS_ATTACHMENTS"

response = requests.get(url)

with open("EA_DS_ATTACHMENTS.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)

print("PDF downloaded successfully!")
```

Of course, it doesn't work. It instead downloads a PDF that is unreadable. I suspect its because it isn't a proper PDF download link, but then again I'm not really sure since im new to this.

Comment: Have you inspected the downloaded content to see what you're actually getting?

Comment: The code looks good. When you get resources from a URL (HTTP) like you did with the requests module, you can access the response's status_code. In your case, it would be response.status_code. I ran your code and got status_code 403, which means "forbidden" (you don't have access to the resource). That's why it isn't working :)

Answer (score 0):

It is returning a 403 response when using requests.  It looks like it is blocking based on the user agent in the headers.  You can use custom headers to mimic your browser's user agent to get the PDF document.

```py
import requests

url = (
    'https://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/apbursaweb/download?'
    'id=231746&name=EA_DS_ATTACHMENTS'
)

res_bad = requests.get(url)
print(res_bad, res_bad.request.headers)

# prints:
# <Response [403]> {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 
# 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

# this is the FireFox user agent
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) '
                         'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0'}

res_good = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open("EA_DS_ATTACHMENTS.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

Comment: I see, so the website is blocking scrapers? Does all websites do that or is it just the secure ones

Comment: It is not blocking scrapers necessarily; it could be they are parsing the user agent so they know which browser you are using and can send back the content that best matches it.  For unknown browsers they return a 404 instead of a fallback.